# YSlow, PhantomJS and Jenkins integration

Tags: jenkins, phantomjs, yslow

I was going through the YSlow official documentation, and I was a little confused by the Jenkins integration part

`http://built-url-here` is the reachable built page url of your project

Because I want to setup so that it can do the speed testing on all the pages of my site ( or a arbitrary number of pages )?

Does the `http://built-url-here`  means a list of urls?  or what?  And how do I define it?  How do I setup just to test a few links for my site??

The doc is here ->  `http://yslow.org/phantomjs/`

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`http://built-url-here` is a single reachable built page url endpoint, it means if you're testing multiple pages you must run the yslow for phantomjs command line multiple times outputing the results into different files, e.g.:

`phantomjs yslow.js -i grade -threshold "B" -f junit http://staging/page1 > yslow1.xml`

`phantomjs yslow.js -i grade -threshold "B" -f junit http://staging/page2 > yslow2.xml`

`phantomjs yslow.js -i grade -threshold "B" -f junit http://staging/page3 > yslow3.xml`

then setting Jenkins output report to check for *.xml